# What does the underscore stand for in the following analogies?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

This is taken from the Miller Analogies Test. No explanation or context is given. My assumption is that the underscore stands for the same operation/number/whatever in both, but I don't know what it would be.

```
_23 : 1.5 :: _ 12 : 0.5

_05 : _05 :: 0 : Undefined
```

Sorry about using *homework* as the only tag, but I don't where else it would fit...?

Comment: Impossible to say.  You need to search for "explanation or context" within the MAT.

Answer (score 2):

Given $23$, we have $2$ into $3$ is $3/2=1.5$

Given $12$, we have $2$ into $1$ is $1/2=0.5$

Given $05$, we have $5$ into $0$ is $0/5=0$

However, $0$ into $5$ is $5/0$ which is undefined.

The pattern is...

> AB : B/A :: CD : C/D